# docker-compose with mysql init script

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I would like to have an application container linked to a mysql container.
The mysql container has an init script that needs to be run on startup.

How do I build a docker-compose file for this scenario?
Using the CMD will disallow the mysql daemon to run.

Comment: What about this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#links ?

Comment: ן don't see how link is related to running an init script..

Comment: Two docker-compose files: first one for the MySQL container that will have a CMD <launch init script>, second one for the application container that will have a links: -db and that could also have a CMD command to run the daemon.

Comment: what image are you using for the mysql container?

Comment: Is my assumption right that you use the init script to create a database schema which is needed by your application? If yes, why does that have to be executed by the MySQL container? Instead I would intuitively place that into the application container which would check during startup if the init script execution is required or not.